# Are both functions equivalent or not, and improvement time in work2 over work1 or not?

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, function, time-complexity

Consider these two functions and two statements S1 and S2 about them.

```
int work1(int *a, int i, int j)
{
    int x = a[i+2];
    a[j] = x+1;
    return a[i+2] - 3;
}
```

---

```
int work2(int *a, int i, int j)
{
    int t1 = i+2;
    int t2 = a[t1];
    a[j] = t2+1;
    return t2 - 3;
}
```

S1: The transformation form `work1` to `work2` is valid, i.e., for any program state and input arguments, `work2` will compute the same output and have the same effect on program state as `work1`.

S2: All the transformations applied to `work1` to get `work2` will always improve the performance (i.e reduce CPU time) of `work2` compared to `work1`.

1. S1 is false and S2 is false
2. S1 is false and S2 is true
3. S1 is true and S2 is false
4. S1 is true and S2 is true

---

AFAIK : Both statements S1 and s2 are true, since both program is equivalent and if CPU used more space, then execution time should be less and vice-versa is also true. So, option (4) is true ( `e.g. Google.com` ).

But, somewhere it given option (1) is true, since when j == i+2 programs will return different results and S2 is false because, it is given high level language. But I didn't get this explanation.

Another explanation said option (3) is true, since Only an extra variable t1 has been added in work 2 instead of directly computing the subscript as in work 1.The output will be same. S1 is true.
The addition of variables t1 and t2 will not improve the performance in anyway. i.e S2 is false.

---

> Can you clarify please? Are both functions equivalent or not, and improvement time in work2 over work1 or not ?

Comment: To me, it looks like S1 is false, like you said (look what happens when j == i + 2). S2 can't be true for every existing compiler and architecture (though for some pairs, I can believe the speed may actually be higher), so it is also false.

Comment: CPU time is very hard to reason about: aspects like caching will have an important impact.

Comment: Also, CPU time would surely depend on the context (number of registers available at the moment, etc).

Comment: More importantly, given that S1 is false (functions don't do the same), S2 does not make sense. You can't sensibly compare the performance of two functions that do different things. And you can't compare CPU times without specifying the CPU. Any aliasing of `a[j]` and `a[i+2]` will be detected and resolved by the CPU at runtime, but the time it takes depends a lot on the **exact** model of CPU.

Comment: 1) There are no programs, but just two functions. 2) Is this C or C++? 3) SO is not "do my homework" site.

Comment: @Olaf, I've edited it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But, somewhere it given option (1) is true, since when j == i+2 programs will return different results and S2 is false because, it is given high level language. But didn't get this explanation.

Bingo. They are both false.

S1 is false because `j` can equal `i+2`, causing `a[j]=x+1` to change the result of `a[i+2] - 3`.

S2 is false (assuming there isn't more context we're supposed to assume) because it is impossible to reason generically that for two bits of code that differ semantically, one must necessarily be faster than the other. Some CPU might have all operations that take four clock cycles except for one that takes one clock cycle and does the exact equivalent of `int x = a[i+2]; a[j] = x+1;`.

To be less silly, `work2` might use more registers than `work1` and this might cause much worse performance in their callers. Or maybe the cost of saving and restoring those registers on function invocation will hurt performance. Maybe `work2` will use just a bit more code cache and push a caller over a performance cliff. Maybe `work2` will be shorter by a few bytes and by sheer bad luck cause a huge cache alignment penalty. Who knows?

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.